# jQuery "bleeding" image transition effect?

Tags: jquery, transition, easing

To make a long story short, the client wants a background fade transition that I don't think is possible with jQuery alone, and I'm looking for some people to confirm that for me (or, if one exists, to point me in the right direction).

My GoogleFu has, as expected, returned nothing.

The transition is from one background to another, with a watercolour-painting-style "colours of current background bleeding out, colours of new background bleeding in" animation.

The "bleeding" I am referring to is best pictured by thinking of a wet paintbrush with red paint touching some clean white paper: the red paint and water would slowly "spread" as the paintbrush is held down in one spot.

Another way of explaining it would be to say that there would be randomization to the "levels" of fading happening - some parts of the first background would fade faster than other parts, etc... all with a smooth "seemless" animation.

I don't believe this exists / is possible with jQuery alone, can anyone confirm?

Comment: You'd have to build a custom animation, and more than likely need to leverage canvas and some fancy image manipulation.

Comment: This may be possible with HTML5 and some heavy calculations, using a canvas, but it'll be nothing to do with jQuery (or maybe a little).  It'll be Javascript, if you can do it at all.

Comment: Yep, knew it. In other words: out of the budget / time scope of the project :P

Comment: Possible? Probably. Easy? Nope.

Comment: I can't see many clients paying the kind of money it would take to spend the time on this, just for a background effect.  Tell them to man up and accept a simple fade :p